# Javascript: 2 arrays with same "weight"

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to figure out how to have 2 arrays balanced by their weight.

I already have an array that stores 10 integers. Like this example:

```
var arrayToSplit = new Array();
arrayToSplit = [1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]; //Total 23
```

I need to take those values and push them to 2 new arrays, but with one condition:

I need to have **the same weight**, or similar, between them AND **both arrays with 5 numbers**. 
So it looks like this.

```
new array = [4, 3, 2, 1, 1]; //Total 11
new array2 = [4, 3, 2, 1, 2]; // Total 12
```

Comment: Do you not know a suitable algorithm or do you just have troubles implementing it?

Comment: Any other conditions? If not... feels like backtracking 2 me. If you add some other constraints like "must have same number of elements", "I know there is always at least one solution", or others... maybe there is a better way.

Comment: I don't know any algorithm. I am thinking of adding all the values ​​of the original array, in this case would give 23. If I divide that, gives 11,5...  so from that point i could push values to one new array until that array has weight equal to 11 (equal to the  result of division). :S

Comment: This is the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). Hopefully the Wikipedia article on this can be some help.

Comment: Thank you gsnedders, I didn't know what was the correct term for that! I will read it. :)

Comment: @zozo it has 2 conditions sorry! each array must have 5 numbers. Thank you for that observation.

Comment: Well... gsnedders already kind of answered it. And better than my n*n/2 first algorithm that poped in my head.

Comment: @gsnedders : elaborate a bit, and this is the answer.

Comment: This is a little bit hard to implement... I guess i need some help. :S

Comment: @zozo well, the problem is np-complete so your runtime can't be that far off :)

Answer (score 2):

I implemented the [pseudo-polynomial algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#The_pseudo-polynomial_algorithm) (did this quite quickly so excuse any errors):

http://jsfiddle.net/536Z2/1/

```
arrayToSplit = [1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]; //Total 23
result = find_partition(arrayToSplit);
console.log(result[0]);
console.log(result[1]);

function find_partition(integers) {
    var array01 = [];
    var array02 = [];
    var partitionedArrays = [];
    var arrayLength = integers.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if (sumArray(array01) <= sumArray(array02)) {
            array01.push(integers[i]);
        } else {
            array02.push(integers[i]);
        }
    }

    partitionedArrays.push(array01);
    partitionedArrays.push(array02);
    return partitionedArrays;
}

function sumArray(array) {
    var count = 0;

    var arrayLength = array.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        count += array[i];
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `for in` on arrays.

Comment: Fails on `[1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 8, 4, 2]`, because it produces one array of length 4 and another of length 6.

Answer (score 1):

I think the possible algorithme that can help you is to sort the array and get shifted elements from it, each time you put an element in an array like this :

```
var arrayToSplit = new Array();
arrayToSplit = [1, 1, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 2]; //Total 23

var array1 = [];
var array2 = []; 


while(arrayToSplit.length>0)
{
    array1.push(arrayToSplit.shift());
    array2.push(arrayToSplit.shift());
}

// Results
array1 = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4]; // Total 11
array2 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4]; // Total 12
```

Comment: This will work for the given set of numbers, but imagine you replace one of the `1` values with an `8` ... an optimal solution would compensate by taking `4`-`4`-`2` in one array and `8`-`1`-`1` in the other; but this algorithm doesn't do that.

Comment: @Jack you're right. I think the OP should give more details, otherwise the solution would be difficult, like getting all the possibilities and calculating each possibility's total, and finally choosing the possibility with near totals